# Python, phoenixdb - not getting a row (but not getting any errors either)

Tags: python, python-3.x, hbase, apache-phoenix, bigdata

I have an Apache Phoenix DB set up and I'm trying to query it using Python with the PhoenixDb plugin.

I have a table with the following rows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PK | did | sensorid | sensor_timestamp | EXTRA_LEVEL | EXTRA_SCALE | EXTRA_HEALTH | EXTRA_STATUS | EXTRA_PLUGGED | EXTRA_PRESENT | EXTRA_VOLTAGE | level_percent | temperature_C | EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY | EXTRA_TEMPERATURE |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I try to query it using phoenixdb it is leaving out 1 row which I am not getting, however I don't get any errors.

My code for the query is:

```
import phoenixdb

connection = phoenixdb.connect(<url>)
cursor = connection.cursor()

query = """select PK,"did", "sensorid", "sensor_timestamp", {3}
           from "sensor_data"
           where "did"='{0}'
           and "sensorid" = '{1}'
           and "sensor_timestamp" > '{2}'
           order by "sensor_timestamp"
           limit 10""".format(357139052213522, 902, 1463163952256, '"EXTRA_LEVEL", "EXTRA_SCALE", "EXTRA_HEALTH", ' \
             '"EXTRA_STATUS" "EXTRA_PLUGGED", "EXTRA_PRESENT", ' \
             '"EXTRA_VOLTAGE", "level_percent", "temperature_C", ' \
             '"EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY","EXTRA_TEMPERATURE"')

cursor.execute(query)

rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

My output is this:

```
['357139052213522_1486731821342_902', '357139052213522', '902', '1486731821342', '64', '100', '2', '2', 'true', '3990', '64.0', '25.0', 'Li-ion', '257']
```

And by counting this, I find that one item is missing.. Does anyone have an idea what this could be due to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. This is a really dumb mistake. I found I was missing a comma in my query.. Fixing that solved it all:

```
query = """select PK,"did", "sensorid", "sensor_timestamp", {3}
       from "sensor_data"
       where "did"='{0}'
       and "sensorid" = '{1}'
       and "sensor_timestamp" > '{2}'
       order by "sensor_timestamp"
       limit 10""".format(357139052213522, 902, 1463163952256, '"EXTRA_LEVEL", "EXTRA_SCALE", "EXTRA_HEALTH", ' \
         '"EXTRA_STATUS", "EXTRA_PLUGGED", "EXTRA_PRESENT", ' \
         '"EXTRA_VOLTAGE", "level_percent", "temperature_C", ' \
         '"EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY","EXTRA_TEMPERATURE"')
```